# Python - Addition of values of a Dictionary within a dictionary based on same Keys

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

so i have 2 dictionaries  within dictionaries.
I need to add the values of the 2 inner dictionaries based on the keys of the outer dictionaries. 
E.g.

```
Dict1 = {A:{1:10,2:20},B:{1:15,2:30},C:{1:2,2:12},D:{1:15,2:40}}
Dict2 = {A:{1:30,2:10},B:{1:10,2:20},C:{1:30,2:20},E:{1:5,2:10}}
```

So, I have to add the values of 1s from Dict1 to values of 2s to Dict2.
e.g for the Key A from both Dictionaries addition of values of 1s from Dict1 and 2s form Dict2: 10 + 10 = 20 and vice versa i.e 2s of Dict1 + 1s of Dict 2: 20 +30 = 50 and create a new dictionary : {A:{up:20,down = 50}}

So desired Output would be :

```
Final_dict = {A:{up:20,down:50},B:{up:35,down:40},c:{up:22,down:42},D:{up:15,down:40},E:{up:10,down:5}}
```

Or simply create separate dictionaries for each addition:

```
Up_Dict = {A:20,B:35,C:22,D:15,E:10}
Down_Dict = {A:50,B:40,C:42,D:40,E:5}
```

What would be the most best way to carry out this addition because both of the dictionaries i have are huge ?

Than you !!

Comment: "optimal"? and what is your optimality criterion?

Comment: right now , Time. Thanks for your quick reply !

Comment: For such small collections you won't ever notice the difference. First try to come up with any solution for yourself. Then you can focus on "optimization", if you really need to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a few dictionary comprehensions. I first populate the two dictionaries with missing keys, then return a dictionary with the desired sum.

```
keys = set(Dict1.keys()+Dict2.keys())
dic1 = {k:Dict1[k] if k in Dict1 else {1:0, 2:0} for k in keys}
dic2 = {k:Dict2[k] if k in Dict2 else {1:0, 2:0} for k in keys}
out = {k:{'up': dic1[k][1]+dic2[k][2], 'down': dic2[k][1]+dic1[k][2]} for k in keys}
```

This gives the following output:

```
{'A': {'down': 50, 'up': 20},
 'B': {'down': 40, 'up': 35},
 'C': {'down': 42, 'up': 22},
 'D': {'down': 40, 'up': 15},
 'E': {'down': 5, 'up': 10}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be worst way

```
keys = Dict1.keys()+Dict2.keys()
>>>[{i:{"up":Dict1[i][1] if i in Dict1 else 0 + \
   Dict2[i][2] if i in Dict2 else 0,"down": Dict1[i][2] \
   if i in Dict1 else 0 + Dict2[i][1] if i in Dict2 else 0 }} \
   for i in set(keys)]


[{'A': {'down': 20, 'up': 10}},
 {'C': {'down': 12, 'up': 2}},
 {'B': {'down': 30, 'up': 15}},
 {'E': {'down': 5, 'up': 10}},
 {'D': {'down': 40, 'up': 15}}]
```

Comment: I thought of putting everything in one comprehension ... but it was not very readable ... so i gave up for my answer :-)